# DVC connect to Min.IO to access S3

Tags: amazon-s3, minio, dvc

What is the proper way to connect DVC to Min.IO that is connected to some buckets on S3.

```
AWS-S3(My_Bucket) > Min.io(MY_Bucket aliased as S3)
```

Right now i am accessing my bucket by using mc for example `mc cp s3/my_bucket/datasets datasets` to copy stuff from there. But I need to setup my DVC to work with min.io as a hub between AWS.S3 and DVC so i can use for example `"DVC mc-S3 pull"` and `"DVC AWS-S3 pull"`.

How do i got for it because while googling i couldn't find anything that i could easily follow.

Comment: Why do you need to access Minio? To download data? To store data? To use as the DVC project cache?

Please look at **S3-compatible storage** in https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/remote/add#supported-storage-types for now.

Comment: I need to do everything that is done on s3 and possible to do on min.io by treating min.io as hub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for a combination of things.

First, Jorge mentioned you can set `endpointurl` to access Minio the same way as you would access regular S3:

```
dvc remote add -d minio-remote s3://mybucket/path
dvc remote modify minio-remote endpointurl https://minio.example.com
```

Second, it seems you can create *two* remotes - one for S3, one for Minio and use `-r` option that is available for many data management related commands:

```
dvc pull -r minio-remote
dvc pull -r s3-remote
dvc push -r minio-remote
...
```

This way you could `push`/`pull` data to/from a specific storage.

> But I need to setup my DVC to work with min.io as a hub between AWS.S3 and DVC

There are other possible ways, I think to organize this. It indeed depends on what semantics you expect from `DVC mc-S3 pull`. Please let us know if `-r` is not enough and clarify the question- that would help us here.

Comment: dvc pull -r X/Y etc is more than enough but i still don't understand one thing.

So if i have a server then i add min.io as you mentioned and that's great, but for me to access my S3 bucket over min.io, I had to install client for min.io, setup it to add s3 storage and then i can use it with command like 'mc cp S3/my_bucket/dataset /dataset'  but i am not sure how i can do it over dvc?

Comment: `access my S3 bucket over min.io ...  add s3 storage` - could you please clarify this a bit? Send me some links to the documentation, may be I'm not that familiar with all the things that Minio could do.

Comment: So the links will be the problem 'cause I cannot find them so I created this topic.
So i got a server hosted on min.io and server hosted on s3. On another PC i got an min.io client that has access to S3 and my min.io server. So thanks to it i can for example do mc copy s3-server/dataset dataset so it copies dataset from S3, then i also can do it for my min.io server with mc copy min-io-server/dataset dataset. And now since i got no other access to min.io server and s3 server i thought it's possible to use mc client as a hub for DVC. Maybe now it's clearer?

Comment: Thanks! I think I have a better idea, but I'm lost on this `as a hub for DVC` still :( What does hub mean? Could you give some examples of the DVC commands that should/would work for you? 

It feels that what you are trying to do is to make DVC use `mc` or its configuration in `pull`, `push`. DVC rely on AWS CLI common configs only and support regular S3 env vars, etc.

Comment: Yea that was my mistake and i tried to use DVC use mc for some reason i thought that should be possible but i guess it's not, but i still got a problem with dvc pull -r X/Y
So i got to my dvc added two storages X (s3 storage), Y (min.io storage). I have two different folders uploaded there X_folder and Y_folder inside a folder dataset. So when i am trying to do dvc pull -r X i am getting a folder dataset/X_folder and when i am trying to do dvc pull -r Y i will get a folder dataset/Y_folder but i am getting X_folder again. Any chance you could tell me how to get that?

Comment: Re `got an min.io client that has access to S3` -
Maybe related to https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-gateway-for-s3.html ?

Comment: Re `but i am getting X_folder again` - @NiewaszBiznes please open a separate follow-up question with all the details to reproduce the issue, or reach out in https://dvc.org/chat